# python if else return confusion, leetcode 669

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return

Leetcode 669.https://leetcode.com/problems/trim-a-binary-search-tree/
Input: root = [1,0,2], low = 1, high = 2.
edit: root is a tree structure expressed in list.
This code got error:

> 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'val'

`if not root` will return, so anything passes this should be not `None`, which has a `val`.

```
def trimBST(self, root: TreeNode, low: int, high: int) -> TreeNode:
    def dfs(root):
        if not root:
            return None
        if root.val < low:         
            root = dfs(root.right)
        if root.val > high:
            root = dfs(root.left)  
        if root.val >= low and root.val <= high:
            root.left = dfs(root.left)
            root.right = dfs(root.right)
        return root            
    return dfs(root)
```

But the following works:

```
def trimBST(self, root: TreeNode, low: int, high: int) -> TreeNode:
    def dfs(root):
        if not root:
            return None
        elif root.val < low:            # OR if root.val < low
            root = dfs(root.right)
        elif root.val > high:
            root = dfs(root.left)  
        else:
            root.left = dfs(root.left)
            root.right = dfs(root.right)
        return root            
    return dfs(root)
```

I am confused why the first doesn't work. I think the `if`s are mutually exclusive, so it will reach the return in the first `if` or through any of the last three to the end.

Comment: I don't understand your code, if `root` is a list, how do does it have a `val` attribute? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `root` is not `None`. Then these lines will be executed:

> ```
> if root.val < low:         
>     root = dfs(root.right)
> if root.val > high:
> ```

Since the second condition is an independent `if` statement, it will be evaluated in any case, even if the two conditions might be mutually exclusive for one and the same `root` object.

Furthermore, if the first condition is fulfilled, `root` now refers to a different object which *might* be `None`, depending on what `dfs(root.right)` returns.

So the expression `root.val > high` might be evaluated with (the new) `root` being `None`.

Whereas in the second example,

> ```
> elif root.val < low:
>     root = dfs(root.right)
> elif root.val > high:
> ```

if the first condition is fulfilled, the second condition will *not* be evaluated, because it is in an `elif` branch. So even if `dfs(root.right)` returns `None`, the condition `root.val > high` will not be evaluated at all.